# Can I define the set of natural numbers without the axiom of infinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The exercise asks if exists a definition of $Nat(x)$ such that $Nat(x) \Rightarrow Nat(S(x))$, and $\exists x $such that $ Nat(x)$ is false without the use of axiom of infinity. Here $Nat(x) \Leftrightarrow x$ is a natural number, and $S(x)$ is the successor of $x$.

I tried to define $$S(a)=\{a\}.$$ Then I define $$a \in C_a \Leftrightarrow (a\in C_a \Rightarrow S(s) \in C_a).$$
So $$\emptyset\in \cap C_i \forall i. $$
At the end I define $$Nat (a) \Leftrightarrow a\in C_\emptyset.$$ 
Can you ckech my idea or suggest another one?

Comment: What does it mean: "$Nat(x)$  is false" ? That there are no *natural* numbers ?

Comment: Maybe [this text](http://pcorazza.lisco.com/drwu/excerpts/infinity-equivalents.pdf) is interesting (or not) for this question.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it means that exist a set that is not a natural number.

Comment: Assuming you are working on $\mathsf{ZF}$ or a similar system (without infinity), you can define the *class* of natural numbers. You will however need the axiom of infinity to prove that it is a set.

Comment: When Zermelo formulated his axioms, he specifically formulated Infinity to *essentially* state "The natural numbers form a set". And now we know that this is necessary as well.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Assuming that is possible define the class of natural, how can do it? This problem is given me by my professor, so I suppose there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot define the set of natural numbers without infinity; but you can define the property of being a natual number:

Define
\begin{equation}
Or(x)\equiv\forall y\in x(y\subset x) \wedge(\forall u,v\in x)(u\in v \vee v\in u \vee v=u);
\end{equation}
"$x$ is and ordinal". Then define,
\begin{equation}
Lim(x)\equiv Or(x)\wedge\forall y\in x\exists z\in x(y\in z);
\end{equation}
"$x$ is a limit ordinal". Finally we make,
\begin{equation}
Nat(x)\equiv x=\emptyset \vee (Or(x)\wedge \neg Lim(x) \wedge \forall y\in x(\neg Lim(y)\vee y=\emptyset))
\end{equation}
To check $Nat(x)\to Nat(S(x))$ remember that the succesor of any ordinal $x$ is $S(x)=x\cup\{x\}$, not $\{x\}$.

Comment: What do you mean with "natual", at the second line? I suppose natural.

Comment: Yes, natural. Typing error, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your attempt.  In particular, you haven't actually defined what "$C_a$" is.  You wrote "$a \in C_a \Leftrightarrow (a\in C_a \Rightarrow S(s) \in C_a)$", but this is circular when taken as a definition (since $C_a$ appears on the right-hand side) and even if it weren't, it would only define when $a\in C_a$, not when $x\in C_a$ for arbitrary $x$.

The other answer describes the standard way to define $Nat(x)$.  Actually, though, for this problem as stated, you can do something much much simpler.  Note that the task of just naming a predicate $Nat(x)$ such that $Nat(x) \Rightarrow Nat(S(x))$ and $\exists x (\neg Nat(x))$ is much easier than actually defining the natural numbers.  For instance, you could define $Nat(x)$ to be $x\neq x$, and then it satisfies these properties.  Slightly less trivially, you could define $Nat(x)$ to be $x\neq \emptyset$, or $x\neq A$ for your favorite set $A$ which is not of the form $S(y)$ for any $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need is some kind of type theory with induction principle.

You just define it like this:

```
N : Type
0 : N
s : N -> N
```

It works in many proof verifier and maybe some functional programming languages.